# Audio Control Center for Linux?

Tags: sound

Preferably something similar to Xonar Audio Center. I use it on Windows and like how easy it is to create custom EQ-settings, switch on 7.1 virtual surround on the fly, and increasing the power given to my headphones by the sound card.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## PulseEffects

Audio effects for Pulseaudio applications

[image]

### Effects Available

#### Applications Output

- Limiter
- Auto Gain
- Expander
- Compressor
- Multiband Compressor
- Equalizer
- Bass Enhancer
- Exciter
- Crystalizer
- Reverberation
- Crossfeed
- Filter (Lowpass, Highpass, Bandpass and Bandreject modes)
- Stereo Tools
- Loudness
- Maximizer
- Gate
- Multiband Gate
- Deesser
- Convolver

#### Applications input

- Gate
- Multiband Gate
- Webrtc
- Limiter
- Compressor
- Multiband Compressor
- Equalizer
- Reverberation
- Pitch
- Filter (Lowpass, Highpass, Bandpass and Bandreject modes)
- Deesser

The user has full control over the effects order. Just use the up/down arrows
next to the plugin label at the left side. To be able to use all plugins you
must have the following installed in your system:

- [GStreamer Plugins Good](https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-plugins-good).
  Version `1.12.5` or higher
- [GStreamer Plugins Bad](https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-plugins-bad).
  Version `1.12.5` or higher
- [Calf Studio Plugins](https://calf-studio-gear.org/). Version `0.90` or higher.
- [ZamAudio Plugins](http://www.zamaudio.com/)
- [MDA.LV2](https://git.drobilla.net/cgit.cgi/mda.lv2.git/about/)
- [libsamplerate](http://www.mega-nerd.com/SRC/index.html)
- [libsndfile](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/)
- [zita-convolver](https://kokkinizita.linuxaudio.org/linuxaudio/)
- [libebur128](https://github.com/jiixyj/libebur128)
  Audio effects for Pulseaudio applications

## Install

To install  [PulseEffects](https://github.com/wwmm/pulseeffects/wiki/Package-Repositories#debian--ubuntu) on Ubuntu >= 18.04 (18.04, 18.10 etc.)  do:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mikhailnov/pulseeffects -y
sudo apt update
sudo apt install pulseeffects pulseaudio --install-recommends
```

PulseAudio >=12 is recommended (see issue #99). It will be installed from this PPA. Ubuntu's patches are ported from Ubuntu 18.10 to 18.04.

These package should, but probably won't be compatible with recent releases of Debian/Deepin and other Debian-based distributions. To try installing PulseEffects on Debian/Deepin:

```
echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/mikhailnov/pulseeffects/ubuntu bionic main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mikhailnov-ubuntu-pulseeffects-bionic.list
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys FE3AE55CF74041EAA3F0AD10D5B19A73A8ECB754 
echo -e "Package: * \nPin: release o=LP-PPA-mikhailnov-pulseeffects \nPin-Priority: 1" | sudo tee /etc/preferences.d/mikhailnov-ubuntu-pulseeffects-ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install pulseeffects
```