# Install Ubuntu18.04.3 on this year's Acer Helios 300 Predator PH315-52 laptop

Tags: nvidia, system-installation, laptop, acer

I bought an [Acer Helios 300 PH315-52](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/support-product/7602) (NVIDIA GTX, 1 TB SSD, i7, 16 GB RAM).
I want to install Ubuntu with a bootable USB, as I did in my last laptop, but I have read that I will have trouble with NVIDIA and WiFi conflicts.

Also, this machine has some apps that are not available on Linux, such as PredatorSense (fan control), and Waves MaxxAudio (sound control equalizer).

Does anyone knows about a method to install Ubuntu on this machine?

Comment: Mmmm, perhaps, but I truly believe my question could help other people

Answer (score 1):

1) Install it using the Ubuntu installer after downloading the ISO for the [release](https://ubuntu.com/download) and  [flavour](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) of Ubuntu you want, and making a [LiveUSB](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0) to install from. If you wish to keep your existing Windows 10 with its special apps, you can do so; the installer lets you create a Dual Boot option where Windows 10 and Ubuntu are installed on their own partitions on your SSD. You won't be apple to run PredatorSense and Waves MaxxAudio in Ubuntu, but you can still use them when you boot from Windows.

If you have NVIDIA and/or WiFi issues, come back here and let us know in a separate question. Please make sure to include what you type in or selected and what error messages you got when you do. It would be very nice, when you say you read about problems, to have the web link back to what you read which concerns you.

2) Once installed, take a look at fan control packages such as [Ubuntu smart fan](https://github.com/ichiriac/ubuntu-smart-fan/blob/master/README.md) and [fan controlling daemon](https://github.com/doitsujin/fand), among [others](https://itsfoss.com/reduce-overheating-laptops-linux/). To replace Waves Maxaudio, there's [Pulse Effects](https://askubuntu.com/a/1077495/197910), [Jack with CALF Plugins](https://medium.com/@kaerumy/ubuntu-linux-high-quality-sound-processing-5be177c556a0), and [LSP](https://lsp-plug.in/), among others. It's Ubuntu, we have answers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I had a Lenovo with Ubuntu and didn't have any problem now I have an Acer but not sure about how to do.   I will try, thanks again for your orientation it is useful certainly

Comment: @minus did you manage to get the fan control on ubuntu. I am having some trouble setting up the fan control. hope you could help

Comment: @AbhayPatil Im sorry for my late answer, I havent tried to install ubuntu and a fan controler, now Im using an acer Helios laptop. Since windows is the Acer's factory OS, didnt want to mess with it cause there is an specific app tool that controls the fans in this laptop.

Comment: @minus I also have predator helios 300. And yeah I have used the predator sense. I was just wondering if you are able to do the fancontrol on the ubuntu. I would say definitely try Ubuntu, you will get sick of windows very soon.