# Predator Sense on Ubuntu

Tags: fan, temperature

I have acer Predator helios 300 PH315-51. I wish to shift to Ubuntu full time and remove Windows 10. However the only thing holding me back is the `Predator Sense` software, which is available for  Windows 10 only. It basically allows you to control the fan speed and monitor the CPU and GPU temperatures. I have managed to get other 3rd party app to monitor temperatures, however I could not find a software to control the fan speed. Is there any way in which I can install `Predator Sense` on Ubuntu, or any other software to control the fan speeds.

**EDIT 1:**
I tried to use wine, but when I run the setup file for predator sense, there is a loading cursor, and then it disappears. And that is it. I tried to run this multiple times.

**EDIT 2:**
I tried using `fancontrol` but when I run `sudo pwmconfig`, I get the following error.

```
This program will search your sensors for pulse width modulation (pwm)
controls, and test each one to see if it controls a fan on
your motherboard. Note that many motherboards do not have pwm
circuitry installed, even if your sensor chip supports pwm.

We will attempt to briefly stop each fan using the pwm controls.
The program will attempt to restore each fan to full speed
after testing. However, it is ** very important ** that you
physically verify that the fans have been to full speed
after the program has completed.

/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed
```

**EDIT 3:**
Basically I am still looking a way to run `Predator Sense` on Ubuntu through some sort of compatibility layer or any other fan control method that works, given that `lm-sensors` does not detect the fan of my laptop.

**EDIT 4:**
The fan sensor isn't detected. See the output of `sensors`:

```
abhay@abhay:~$ sensors
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +46.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +45.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +46.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +43.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +43.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 4:        +43.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 5:        +44.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

pch_cannonlake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +53.0°C  

iwlwifi_1-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +44.0°C  

BAT1-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
in0:          16.68 V  
curr1:         0.00 A
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try if `fancontrol` works for you:

**Installation:**

```
sudo apt-get install fancontrol
```

**Configuration:**

```
sudo pwmconfig
```

Here you can find and select the fan you want to control and the sensor that should be used to measure the temperature.

If fancontrol works for you you should enable it with this:

```
sudo systemctl enable fancontrol
```

`fancontrol` is sometimes tricky (at least on thinkpad in my experience) but give it a try!

**BTW** (you didn't ask but I'll tell you anyway ;-))

For monitoring temperatures and fan speed I use lm-sensors with psensor:
Installation and configuration:

```
sudo apt-get install lm-sensors psensor
sudo sensors-detect
sudo service kmod start
```

`sensors-detect` will ask you for all sensors that are found if you want to use them. Go for the default, except in the last step when it asks you

```
Do you want to add these lines automatically to /etc/modules? (yes/NO)
```

type in `yes` and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. Good luck!

Comment: Pls check the edit 2 part I added in my question.

Comment: Hmmm, pity. Just because I'm curious: Could you try to install `lm-sensors` and test if `sensors-detect` finds any pwm fans? I don't think so but I would try it.

Comment: No there is pwm fans. So does that mean, I cant use `fancontrol`?

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe it's due to missing drivers, but I can't seem to find a linux driver package for the predator. I found this instead: https://askubuntu.com/a/1171375/752882 I don't know "smart fan" and "fan controlling daemon" but maybe that works.

Answer (score 0):

I recently created a config(nbfc) file for Acer Predator Helios 300(RTX 2060) and this is working flawlessly for me.
Hope it will also work for you.
https://github.com/hirschmann/nbfc/pull/1039/files#diff-50ddd4e9ba6abe03c49bc65914eb62a60b506a5ce12e46df5857e012a7584390

Comment: on running `sensors`, did it detect the fan sensors? Check my edit 4

Comment: no i just follow the nbfc wiki and the ec-probe tool helped me alot to create this config

Comment: so even without detecting the sensors, this will work??

Comment: before asking so many question why you don't use this config

Comment: look man the config file i created it's work like a charm for me i thought like me many users are facing the same problem(controlling the fan speed) they should give it a try, if it's help them, that's why i am posting the link in many forums, before asking any question give it a try , if you really want to know how this all work go and read the nbfc wiki

Comment: I tried it. Now my doubt is how to control the speed? Do I have to change the config file to control it??

Comment: And also I think I might have tor update the registers for my laptop, can you tell which method to find the registers worked for you?? Apparently the first two methods are not working for me. So I might have to go for the third method, which is a bit risky.

Comment: And apparently your configuration is not working for me, as the target speeds and current speeds of the fan differ by a large amount. Hence I would have to find my MoBo's EC registers myself.